# Различия между одним и тем же SVG элементом в Chrome и Firefox, как исправить?

Tags: svg

Имеется следующий SVG элемент

```html
<svg height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" class="maplibre-gl-directions-bearings-control__waypoint-image" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; opacity: 1;"><circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="transparent" stroke="rgba(109, 38, 215, 0.65)" stroke-width="10" stroke-dasharray="calc(12.5 * 31.42 / 100) 31.42" transform="rotate(-61.5)" style="transform-origin: 10px 10px;"></circle><circle r="6" cx="10" cy="10" fill="rgb(109, 38, 215)"></circle></svg>
```

Он отображается корректно в Chrome:

[image: Chrome]

А вот в Firefox он выглядит по-другому:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Вопрос**: что не нравится Firefox'у и что сделать чтобы исправить ситуацию?

Comment: Я не уверен что в `stroke-dasharray` можно использовать `calc`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я не уверен что в `stroke-dasharray` можно использовать `calc`, но судя по коду вам на самом деле нужно просто нарисовать 1/8 круга. Можно это делать без `calc` и вычисления длины окружности при помощи [`pathLength`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/pathLength):

```html
<svg height="20" width="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" style="width: 50px; height: 50px">
    <circle r="5" cx="10" cy="10" fill="transparent"
        stroke="rgba(109, 38, 215, 0.65)" stroke-width="10"
        pathLength="100"
        /* объявляем что длина окружности 100 */
        stroke-dasharray="12.5 100"
        /* и не заморачиваемся сложными вычислениями */
        transform="rotate(-61.5)"
        style="transform-origin: 10px 10px;">
    </circle>
    <circle r="6" cx="10" cy="10" fill="rgb(109, 38, 215)">
    </circle>
</svg>
```

Comment: Да, действительно проблема была в `calc`. Нет, там необязательно должна быть именно четверть круга, значения подставляются динамически, использую Svelte. В общем, убрал `calc`, заменил на обычное математическое выражение, и все заработало: `stroke-dasharray="{((waypointBearing.degrees / 3.6) * 31.42) / 100} 31.42"`. Спасибо за наводку!

Comment: Про `path-length` вообще не знал. Переделывать уже не буду, но все равно спасибо!

Comment: А если у вас на входе градусы, то ещё проще объявить длину окружность в 360 и вообще ничего считать не нужно